# Inserting specific values into a DB, and displaying it on a table?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, insert

I'm trying to insert specific values(knife, and blanket) into a Database, but's not inserting into the DB/table at all. Also, I want to display the inserted values in a table below, and that is not working as well. It is dependant on the insert for it to show on the table. I am sure, because I inserted a value through phpmyAdmin, and it displayed on the table. Please, I need to fix the insert aspect.

The Insert Code/Error Handler

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Collect'])) {
if(($_POST['Object'])!= "knife" && ($_POST['Object'])!= "blanket")
{
  echo "This isn't among the room objects.";
}else {
// this makes sure that all the uses that sign up have their own names
$sql = "SELECT id FROM objects WHERE object='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Object'])."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$m_count = mysql_num_rows($query);

 if($m_count >= "1"){
    echo 'This object has already been taken.!';
    } else{
   $sql="INSERT INTO objects (object)
VALUES
('$_POST[Object]')";

echo "".$_POST['object']." ADDED";
}
} 
} 

?>
```

TABLE PLUS EXTRA PHP CODE

```
<p>
<form method="post">
</form>
Pick Object: <input name="Object" type="text" />  
<input class="auto-style1" name="Collect" type="submit" value="Collect" />
</p>

<table width="50%" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
      <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="3">Player&#39;s Object</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Object</td>
      </tr>
      <?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM objects") or die(mysql_error());
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table?>
      <tr>
       <td><label for="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php
    $name2=$row['id'];
    echo "$name2"; ?>
    </label></td>
        <td><? echo $row['object'] ?></td>
      </tr>
        <?php }// while loop ?>
    </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(($_POST['Object'])!= knife || ($_POST['Object'])!= blanket)
```

THese value knife and blanket are string. So you may need to use quotes around them to define them as string, or php won't understand ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key of Objects is id and it is set to auto-increment

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO objects SET id = '', object = '".$_POST['Object']."'";
```

try

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO objects(object) VALUES ('".$_POST['Object'].")';
```

and you should probably put an escape in there too

Answer (score 0):

You insert query is nor correct.

$sql = "INSERT INTO objects (id, object) values('','".$_POST['Object']."') ";

and this code

```
if(($_POST['Object'])!= "knife" || ($_POST['Object'])!= "blanket")
{
  echo "This isn't among the room objects.";
}
```

will always be executed value of object is knife or blanket, because a variable can have one value. You must use

```
if(($_POST['Object'])!= "knife" && ($_POST['Object'])!= "blanket")
    {
      echo "This isn't among the room objects.";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL syntax is wrong.  You should change the:

```
INSERT INTO objects SET id = '', object = '".$_POST['Object']."'
```

to

```
INSERT INTO objects ( id, object ) VALUES ('', '".$_POST['Object']."'
```

If you want your inserts to also replace any value that might be there use REPLACE as opposed to INSERT.

Comment: Thank You. I have fixed that bit, but it still doesn't work. Please check the error handling if the problem comes from there